# Server not Responding

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, administration

This is my QA environment. My web front end started showing up in the health analyzer a couple of days ago under 'One or more servers is not responding'. I did some research and tried numerous times to clear the cache, remove the  server from the farm and add it back again using the psconfig, remove the  server/clear the cache/re-add the server but the issue still persists.

I need to get this resolved but am running out of ideas. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things to do.

- Make sure the SharePoint timer Service is running and should be running under the farm admin account
- Once you removed the server from Farm, from central admin > make sure Server is no more Listed. Central Admin> system Setting > manager Server in farm...
- Run the Get-SPproduct -local on all servers
- Dont forget to reanalyze the Health rule.

Comment: Hi Waqas. Are you saying to run Get-SPproduct -local on the non-responsive WFE as well as all other servers after I've removed the WFE from the farm? - thanks

Comment: after removing server from farm then run this on remaining servers then re analyze the rule.

Comment: I will try this this evening. Today it stopped responding so I cleared the cache on it, then ran psconfig -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -force which kicked out "An exception of type Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPUpdatedConcurrencyException was thrown." So I ran stsadm -o setproperty -pn command-line-upgrade-running -pv No and then the psconfig again and it completed successfully. The Web  Publishing Service had to be restarted and then I cleared the cache again and then the server began responding again. Its resuscitation is definitely linked tot that psconfig.

Comment: So I removed the WFE from the farm using psconfigui. I then went to the APP and the App running SSRS in integrated and ran Get-SPproduct -local. WHen they completed I added the wfe back into the farm. Reanalyzed..still not responding. So I ran the psconfigui on it again, reanalyzed...not responding.

Comment: How you add the server in the farm, running config wizard? this is weird that you just add server and analyzer rule says it is not responding...

Comment: one thing, check from central admin > System Settings> manage servers in farm....what is status of servers?

Comment: All servers, including the non responsive WFE says 'No Action Required'. This is despite  the health analyzer showing the WFE as 'not Responding'.

Comment: Still No luck. I disconnected the WFE from the config via psconfig -cmd configdb -disconnect. Afterwards I could still see this server in the Manage Servers interface as before. 
Perhaps you need to click 'Remove Server' on the Manage Servers page before that happens.
I then added the server back and ran some config commands all of which completed successfully:
psconfig -cmd configdb -connect -server <SQLServerNameOrAlias> -database <SPCOnfigDBName> -PassPhrase <passphrase>
psconfig -cmd services install
psconfig -cmd installfeatures
psconfig -cmd secureresources

Comment: When you remove the server and if you are still seeing in central admin then you have to remove it from there as well...click on remove server.

Comment: I reran your initial guidance after removing the server from farm both via the psconfigui and from the Manage Servers interface. Now the rule disappeared. Also, the orphaned SSRS service that was on the wfe disappeared. It had been reading 'Stopping' for months. I will know for sure in several hours whether this worked or not as the rule has been popping back up after a while in past 'successes'. i'll post back.

Comment: Great, you can re ran the rule manually by going to central admin...also now try to add server back in farm

Comment: Yes, I added the WFE back to the farm before reanalyzing and it has not reappeared. I'll see if I can find that particular rule and run it again, but being able to get results from the wfe when running merge-splogfile is a good indication of successes this previously warned that it was unable to return results from the wfe. It usually takes several hours for it to become unresponsive after a fix so I'll test again in the AM and post back here. Thanks!

Comment: The  WFE made it overnight without becoming non-responsive. I'm going to call it fixed! The solution was to follow Waqas initial guidance to the 'T' and remove the server from the Manage Servers page. Prior to removing I ran the psconfigUI to remove the server from the farm. Many thanks!